# Issuing one-to-one inter-player challenges

Tags: unity

I have a small game I have written in Unity (at present only for Android). It is a very simple game where you get more points the longer you last. Nothing complicated.

In order to help "spread the word," I want to enable players to challenge others to see who can score higher. I am not talking about their all-time high scores (these I save in the Google Game Play leaderboards).

How can I easily manage a one-to-one challenge?

I can't seem to find a straight forward way to do it using the Google SDK.
It has the turn based play option but in my case each one plays separately. When both have played, the results get compared.

Short of setting up my own backend, how can I go about this?

Note: I am happy to use the FB SDK if necessary since that is how the challenges will be generally sent.

Comment: You mention the Facebook SDK. Does that mean that the communication medium you want to use to invite people to the game is a Facebook direct message?

Comment: @Philipp I figured that that was the easiest way to reach people that are not already subscribers to the game. I could use other social media too so it is not essential to be FB.

Answer (score 1):

You already seem to have a way of sending challenges using the FB SDK, so we'll skip right ahead to actual challenge matches; In short all you need to do is keep a database entry of the score the other user had and send along the ID of the match in your challenge requests.

If there is more information you need to save, say it is head to head gameplay and not competitive single player then things get a bit more complicated as you need to essentially save the gamestate along with the ID, but it doesnt seem to be the case for you as your game is competitive single player.